# Invalid Use of property vba class

Tags: vba, excel, properties

I have the Student class in VBA (Excel) implemented as follows

```
Option Explicit

Private name_ As String
Private surname_ As String
Private marks_ As New Collection


Public Property Get getMean() As Single

    Dim sum As Double
    Dim mark As Double
    Dim count As Integer

    For Each mark In marks_
        sum = sum + mark
        count = count + 1
    Next mark

    getMean = sum / count

End Property

Public Property Let setName(name As String)
    name_ = name
End Property

Public Property Get getName() As String
    getName = name_
End Property

Public Property Let setSurname(surname As String)
    surname_ = surname
End Property

Public Property Get getSurname() As String
    getSurname = surname_
End Property
```

Then I have a main sub where I write:

```
Dim stud1 As New Student

stud1.setName "Andy"
```

I got a compile error on `stud1.setName "Andy"` : Invalid use of property. 
I don't understand why. Any Idea, please?

Comment: On top of the accepted answer; `GetMean()` seems invalid to me; `marks` is not dimensioned anywhere unless it's a typo cause you're missing the underscore at the end `_`. Also an iterator in a for each loop has to be a variant type - you've got a double. Also what is the point of having public properties if both the setter and getter are public? Instead of having two properties just dimension `name` and `surname` as public variables and VBA will treat them like a class' *properties*

Comment: You are rigth mehow. For `getmean()` it was a typo. It would definitely be more efficient to have public `name` and `surname. This is just for academic purpose.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since it's a *property* (not method) you should use `=` to apply a value:

```
Dim stud1 As New Student

stud1.setName = "Andy"
```

---

BTW, for simplicity, you can use the same name for `get` and `set` properties:

```
Public Property Let Name(name As String)
    name_ = name
End Property

Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = name_
End Property
```

and then use them as follows:

```
Dim stud1 As New Student
'set name
stud1.Name = "Andy"
'get name
MsgBox stud1.Name
```

Comment: Of course you are right concerning the properties names. You helped me understand the "property" concept. Thanks

Comment: +1 simoco good answer but see my above comment I am sure you know that :)

Comment: @mehow, thanks! I was concentrated on the "main" problem of OP's question: `stud1.setName = "Andy"`, and didn't pay attention on `getMean` property, my fault:) but it is very good that you pointed out OP errors)